# Передать аргумент в декоратор

Tags: python, декоратор

Привет!

Мне нужно передать простой аргумент(строку) в декоратор. Не понимаю, как это сделать.

```
def timing(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        time_start = timer()
        ret = function(*args, **kwargs)
        spent_time = round(timer() - time_start, 5)

        return ret, spent_time
    return wrapper
```

Пытался так:

```
def timing(function, string=''):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        time_start = timer()
        ret = function(*args, **kwargs)
        spent_time = round(timer() - time_start, 5)
        print string
        return ret, spent_time
    return wrapper
```

И вызывать так:

```
 @timing(string='getting statement')
    def check_statement(self):
        if bool(self.state):
            return
```

Вылетает с ошибкой:

```
@timing(message='')
TypeError: timing() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Пытался завернуть в еще один декоратор:

```
def timing(function, message):
    def clock(message):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            time_start = timer()
            ret = function(*args, **kwargs)
            spent_time = round(timer() - time_start, 5)

        return wrapper# ret, spent_time
    return clock
```

Traceback:

```
    @timing(message='')
TypeError: timing() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Помогите пожалуйста сделать правильно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот:

```
def decorator(s):
    def wrap(function):
        def called(*args, **kwargs):
             print(s, function, args, kwargs)
             return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return called
    return wrap


@decorator('example')
def f(num):
    print(num)


f(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать functools.partial при указании декоратора у функции:

```
@functools.partial(timing, string='getting statement')
def check_statement(self):
    if bool(self.state):
        return
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_decor(func, add):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs) + add
    return wrap

def summ_(a, b=0):
    return a + b

add_decor(summ_, add=100)(1, b=1)  # 102
summ_add = add_decor(summ_, add=10)
summ_add(1, b=1)  # 12
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]